# Count the checked checkboxes in xaml xamgrid checkbox column

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF xaml application, In that case I have already developed a `GridView` for represent the data in DB. Now I want to add a `CheckBoxColumn` to my GridView . the purpose select the DataRows in GridView by checking CheckBoxes. Also I want to count number of checked CheckBoxes in that column. I am new to programming so I haven't  an idea about this. please help me. Thank you!

```
<ig:XamGrid.Columns>
     <ig:TextColumn Key="Date" Width="150" HeaderText="date" />
     <ig:TextColumn Key="Name" Width="100" HeaderText="name" />
     <ig:TextColumn Key="Id" Width="120" HeaderText="id" />
     <ig:TextColumn Key="Detail" Width="300" HeaderText="detail" />
     <ig:CheckBoxColumn Key="Select" Width="100" HeaderText="select" />
</ig:XamGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ItemsSource property on XamGrid databinding should update source collection and you should be able simply to do:

```
var count = rows.Where(r=>r.select).Count();
```

Where rows is your data collection.

**UPDATE 1:**

I don't have XamGrid but if you use standard DataGrid it would look like this:

```
Data = new ObservableCollection<Step2Data>
    {
        new Step2Data { LayerName = "Ania"},
        new Step2Data { LayerName = "Bartek", Accept = true},
        new Step2Data { LayerName = "Omega"},
        new Step2Data { LayerName = "Second"},
    };
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Layer name" Binding="{Binding LayerName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Porosity" Binding="{Binding Porosity}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Accept" Binding="{Binding Accept, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And to count selected:

```
var count = Data.Count(d => d.Accept);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you please give me a example??

Comment: thank you very much, but my grid view is a xaml xamgrid. so there is no property named "Binding"  , which properties should use ?

Comment: Probably Key property e.g. <ig:TextColumn Key="LayerName" ... />. But if you wish to learn WPF don't use custom third-party controls like xamgrid.